# Cant run any npm command after updating npm

Tags: npm

After i use `npm install` on a new cloned git project, i got this information about the new major verion of npm. since it's a major update as it says so i do the
update command `npm install -g npm` and my update did not success.

[image]

so every time i do these command (image below), i got same error result.

[image]

Any solution for this? thankyou.